# Passing the query count in javascript variable

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

See i have below Code in my javascript

```
var itemCount = 5, activeScroll = 0, countScroll = 0;
setInterval(function() {
    if(countScroll == (itemCount - 2))
    {                  
        activeScroll = 0;
        countScroll = 0;
        $('#list').animate({scrollTop: 0});
    }
    else
    {
        activeScroll += 250;
        countScroll += 1;
        $('#list').animate({scrollTop: activeScroll});            
    }

}, 2000);
```

and my query string in php code is

```
$userads = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_ads ORDER BY `user_addate` DESC");
$adcount = mysql_num_rows($userads);
```

i am trying to assign value of `$adcount` in javascript variable var `itemCount`;

query is running in `test.php` and javascript is `scroller.js`.

Please help me .

Comment: You cannot use value PHP variable directly in external javascript file. Make an ajax request to test.php and return the count value.

Comment: Thanks @Samir .. Could you suggest me how to do it ?? i am a beginner in this area ..

Comment: See Tsalikidis's post for an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can output javascript by test.php:

```
<?php
    $userads = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_ads ORDER BY `user_addate` DESC");
    $adcount = mysql_num_rows($userads);
?>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var itemCount = <?php echo $adcount; ?>;
    setupTimer(itemCount);
</script>
```

Make sure the scroller.js defines the function `setupTimer(itemCount)` that performs the task you want, instead of firing right away.

Answer (score 0):

in `scroller.js` type this code:

```
                $.ajax("test.php", {
                type: 'post',
                data: {
                    count:itemCount
                },
                sync: true,
                success: function (adcount) {
                    itemCount=adcount;
                }

            });
```

in `test.php`type this code:

```
if (isset($_POST['count']))
{
echo $adcount;
exit;
}
```

**notice**:you should use `jquery` file in your script for `ajax`

Answer (score 0):

First you need to request the value from the server. Then you can assign it.

```
var itemCount;

setInterval(function() {
  $.get('test.php', function(response) {
    itemCount = response.itemCount;
    // you scroll logic here
  }, 'json');
}, 2000);
```

In test.php you should output the value by something like this:

```
$output = array(
  "itemCount" => $adcount
);
print json_encode($output);
```

Comment: When you get more familiar with ajax and PHP you will see that there is no magic here and there are many ways to do this.